# Encoding JSON in Mako?

Tags: python, json, mako

Im having trouble with json in mako.  I do this:

```
${ to_json( dict( a = 1, b = 2 ) ) }
```

where to_json is:

```
<%!
    import simplejson as json

    def to_json( d ):
        return json.dumps( d )
%>
```

however, instead of giving me

```
{"a": "1", "b": "2"}
```

its giving me

```
{&quot;a&quot;: 1, &quot;b&quot;: 2}
```

so mako changes the " to " somewhere

what should i be doing instead?

in contrast, heres a test script

```
import simplejson as json

print json.dumps( dict( a=1,b=2 ) )
```

output

```
{"a": 1, "b": 2}
```

**edit**

i changed my function to

```
<%!
    import simplejson as json

    def to_json( d ):
        return "{\"a\": 1}"
%>
```

and it changes the " to `&quot;`, so its an issue with mako, it seems.

Comment: Isn't that just because you outputted it to a HTML page?!

Comment: I need it as a parameter to JS, but no, the difference is it should not be encoded.

Comment: Please show the code that inserts the result of `to_json(...)` into your output. Somewhere in the middle of a JavaScript block I guess...

Comment: This is pretty much it, it's standard mako.  i will edit it

Comment: I don't have any knowledge about Mako (yet). Could you try `${ to_json( dict( a = 1, b = 2 ) ) | n }` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like theres an auto filter somewhere, so when i changed

```
${ to_json( dict( a = 1, b = 2 ) ) }
```

to

```
${ to_json( dict( a = 1, b = 2 ) ) | n }
```

to turn off filters, it is okay, thanks

Comment: Be thankful for the filter, it's there to help keep javascript injection/XSS from biting you!  But a pain when you don't want it.

Comment: It'd be nice if you could in some way tell Mako to ignore default filters anytime this filter is used. Otherwise, it's a pain